# Oauth2 token request does not contain redirect_uri

Tags: oauth-2.0, bitbucket, micronaut

I'm trying to setup an Oauth2 Authoization Code flow with Bitbucket Oauth in micronaut.
I've setup both Github and Bitbucket in my Mirconaut config for auth.

Whenever I (try to) login with Bitbucket, I get an redirect_uri does not match error.

`{"message":"Internal Server Error: error: invalid_request, errorDescription: redirect_uri does not match, errorUri: null"}`

After doing some research and enabling some trace logging I see that redirect_uri is missing in the access token request.

```
09:33:53.263 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-5] DEBUG i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - Sending HTTP Request: POST /site/oauth2/access_token
09:33:53.263 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-5] DEBUG i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - Chosen Server: bitbucket.org(-1)
09:33:53.264 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-5] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - Accept: application/json
09:33:53.264 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-5] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - Authorization: Basic xxxxxxx
09:33:53.264 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-5] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
09:33:53.264 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-5] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - host: bitbucket.org
09:33:53.264 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-5] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - connection: close
09:33:53.264 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-5] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - content-length: 53
09:33:53.264 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-5] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - Request Body
09:33:53.264 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-5] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - ----
09:33:53.264 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-5] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - code=PuaUDFGTmQ4Gh9gJPM&grant_type=authorization_code
09:33:53.264 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-5] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - ----
09:33:53.762 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-5] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - HTTP Client Response Received for Request: POST https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token
09:33:53.762 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-5] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - Status Code: 400 Bad Request
```

Whenever I recreate the call with something like curl and add the (default) redirect_uri, I get back a proper access token and am able to use this.

Is there any way to add the redirect_uri to the token request? Is this a bug? As far as I know, the redirect_uri is required in the token request, if it was also present in the previous authorization request (see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3)

Thanks,

Danny

Comment: This seems like a bug, please file an issue

Comment: Already filed under https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-security/issues/93

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when setting up OAuth2 on Bitbucket using Tornado. I hope it helps you track down this issue specifically in micronaut

As you know, there are two stages to the authentication.

1. Authorize (https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/authorize) which returns a token and
2. Authorization code grant (https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token)

They both take a redirect_uri in the POST body but they have to be *identical* for both calls. As long as they start with the same uri that is specified in the OAuth consumer settings in Bitbucket (e.g https://f.q.d.n/), they can point to a more specific path (e.g https://f.q.d.n/some/specific/end-point)

Importantly, they must be the same for both calls or you will be the redirect_uri does not match error.